# Help with modeling issue (Paper folds on the corners of a package)

Tags: modeling, texturing, bevel, extrude

I just started using Blender and I'm losing my mind over this little issue. I have to model a box for product packaging and, to make it as realistic as possible I need to model the corner to show that there is paper over it (as in the picture).

I tried a lot of methods but I end up messing with the mesh or not being able to use the bevels. Do you know a simple method to recreate this fold?

Thank you very much guys.

[image: Image of the box]

Comment: you could just extrude a bit, or fake it with normal map or bump map, or with a texture?

Comment: I know it's a dumb question, but If can I extrude faces in different directions altogether? (I'll show you the problem in the video) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m8am6-6_DMC2k6IyfJPUL2qzQ-pg0BHX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how detailed you want your object to be, if you want to make close-up shots you'll need to take care of this part, if it's not the case you don't need to work this part a lot. You can also fake the bump. But if you want to model it, you can create an edge loop:

[image]

Then extrude a bit on Y, then a bit on Z:

[image]

Then add bevels to round the edges:

[image]

Here is what it will give (the extrusion is probably too strong here but it is for demonstrastion):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for using your time to do this mini-tutorial! it was really helpful!